# How can clear this setInterval?

Tags: javascript

```
start.on('click', function(){
  setInterval(time, 1000);

  object.animate({ marginTop: '500px' }, 3000, function () {
    normaal.fadeIn(700);
  });
});


function time() {
  change.textContent = Number(change.textContent) + 50;
}
```

How excatly can I stop (clear) this `setInterval`. I want it to automatically start after 3000 miliseconds once the even has been called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` keeps calling the method over and over. What you want is to use [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) instead, which will call the method once (and only once) after waiting the specified period of time. You can use `clearTimeout` if you want to prevent a `setTimeout` call from executing.

```
setTimeout(time, 3000);
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you also happen to know how can make the animation go faster by the second. Just like gravity I want the animation to speed up with time.

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question since then you'll get more/better answers. I can't say I know too much about animation, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `clearInterval` method.

`var intervalID =  setInterval(time, 1000);`

> The returned value of `setInterval` is a numeric, non-zero value which
>   identifies the timer created by the call to setInterval(); this value
>   can be passed to WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.clearInterval() to cancel
>   the timeout.

and then to `clearInterval`, pass the `intervalID` like `clearInterval(intervalID)`;

Also, `setInterval` calls the callback **repeatedly**, if you need to execute a code block only once then use *setTimeout* instead.

Answer (score -1):

```html
var interval;

start.on('click', function () {
  interval = setInterval(time, 1000);

  object.animate({ marginTop:'500px' }, 3000, function () {
    normaal.fadeIn(700);
  });
});


function time() {
  change.textContent = Number(change.textContent) + 50;
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```